# How to open a python file in idle editor by double clicking on the file (windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, anaconda, python-idle

Anaconda 5.2 (python 3.6) was installed in windows 10 for a single user.

How to open, in the idle editor (**mandatory**) , a python file by simply double clicking on it?

Trying to associate .py to idle by doing right click > property > ...idle.exe fails to open the file directly in the idle editor.

Up to now to open a py file with the idle editor it is necessary to do:

1. open *anaconda promp* from menu (a virtual env (base) is opened)
2. type idle from (base) environment
3. from idle menu open the file.py

Comment: Double clicking a file is usually meant to run rather than edit, but you can, of course, customize your system.  The python.org installer adds 'Edit with IDLE' to the right-click context menu.  I suspect Anaconda installer does not.

Answer (score 2):

Set the file association to the `idle.bat` file.
for me this is located here:

```
C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\idlelib
```

You can create a custom icon association to the original python icon too if you want.